# How can I add the title to <th> in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

i am doing a homework in vuejs. Now i want add title to  tag in vue
below is my code

`tbody table:`

```
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(employee) in employees" :key="employee.EmployeeId">
                    <td>{{employee.EmployeeCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.FullName}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.GenderName}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">{{employee.DateOfBirth|dateofbirth}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.PhoneNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.Email}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.PositionName}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.DepartmentName}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">{{employee.Salary|money}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.WorkStatus|status}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Now i want to add title to `<td>` like `<td title="{{employee.Email}}">{{employee.Email}}</td>`
Please help me thanks so much

Comment: You can achieve it with `:title="employee.Email"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can something like

```
<td :title="employee.Email">{{employee.Email}}</td>
```

Comment: thank u so much it's working

Comment: Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would upvote the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have.